# Why would Moshe's new nation have been considered a one legged chair?

Tags: talmud-gemara, moshe-rabbeinu, pentateuch-chumash, golden-calf-egel, maharsha

Bavli Berachos (32a) contains the following aggadic assertion

> {שמות ל"ב:י'} וְאֶעֱשֶׂה אוֹתְךָ לְגוֹי גָּדוֹל וְגוֹ', אֲמַר רִבִּי אֶלְעָזָר: אָמַר מֹשֶׁה לִפְנֵי הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא, רִבּוֹנוֹ שֶׁל עוֹלָם, וּמַה כִּסֵּא שֶׁל שָׁלֹשׁ רַגְלַיִם (רש"י – אברהם יצחק ויעקב) אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לַעֲמוֹד לְפָנֶיךָ בְּשָׁעַת כַּעֲסָךְ, כִּסֵּא שֶׁל רֶגֶל אֶחָד, עַל אַחַת כַּמָּה וְכַמָּה!
>
> In the same verse, God promised Moses: “And I will make of you a great nation.” What was Moses’ response? Rabbi Elazar said: Moses said before the Holy One, Blessed be He: Master of the Universe, if a chair with three legs, the collective merit of the three forefathers, is unable to stand before You in Your moment of wrath, all the more so that a chair with one leg, my merit alone, will be unable to withstand your wrath.

The question is that as Moshe is himself descended from Avraham, Yitzchak and Yaakov why would a new nation of his be considered a one legged chair and not a 4 legged one?

([Maharsha](https://shas.alhatorah.org/Dual/Maharsha_Chidushei_Aggadot/Berakhot/32a.17#m7e0n6), owing to this q, indeed writes that the gemara really means a four legged chair, see there. I am looking for another interpretation as it does not seem to be the straightforward meaning of the gemara. I see now that [Maharal](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Gur_Aryeh/Shemot/32.13#m4e0n6) in Gur Aryeh also addresses this issue and explains that the language connotes a disassociation from the Avos and a kind of restart where Moshe would somehow be considered the sole Av)

Comment: @RabbiKaii What's the other interpretation?

Comment: I think I could hear it either way, but I don't think the question bothers me. It seems quite possible that it is not a fulfillment of Hashem's promise to the Avos, to completely exterminate their descendants except for one, generations later, even if that one later grows to be a great nation.

Comment: The ben yohada has two different answers. https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Yehoyada_on_Berakhot.32a.7?lang=bi

Comment: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52156&st=&pgnum=352&hilite=

Answer (score 0):

My friend suggested that according to the [Astrovtza Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_Yechiel_Halevi_Halstock) when the Jewish nation converted at Mt. Sinai they were forced to do so and that according to Maharal you don't say that such a convert is like a newborn child. But Moshe was on top of the mountain so he wasn't forced, so his conversion made him like a newborn child so he wasn't related to the Avos (Patriarchs).

Comment: I thought Maharal says that as the nation converted as a whole vs an individual we don't say גר שנתגייר וכו. Do you know where it is?

Comment: So Moshe's descendants don't have zechus avos?

Comment: @Nahum its maharal qouted in hakdama to shav shmaisa os 9. Its gur aryeh vayigash

Comment: Moshe didnt go up the mountain till after the coercion

Comment: @Nahum it seems its accepted moshe was on top. The cli chemda (vayigash)  also understands moshe was on top of mountain. (Though he was challenging the shaimsa because of that)