# Can Earth exist without Heaven?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy

Science and materialism claim that everything about this world can be explained in terms of materialism. Stuff, and the maths that governs the rules of that stuff, basically, is all there is.

Does Torah at least confirm that this is *possible*? Can we envision a world with matter, planets, animals and humans all existing purely physically, without any need for a spiritual, above-the-physical soul? Or do our sources claim emphatically that this world **cannot** exist without the spiritual?

Answers from across the board are sought.

---

Note: I am not asking if Hashem *can* make a physical universe without needing Heaven. I am asking if *this* physical universe *can* exist without Heaven. I would also like to state that this question does not assume that God is "spiritual". Therefore I am not beggin the question "can the world exist without God".

Comment: As a sweeping general statement I would say that Plato held that there is a higher realm of forms which is truly real which kabbalists typically adopt with Aristotle arguing that form is not separate from matter which is what the rationalist rishonim seem to adopt

Comment: @Nahum Thank you. To keep it simple, I've included that in the "maths that governs the rules", like the materialists. So can the world exist with only the physical and the platonic, or does it need a spiritual element as well. Or even simpler: are materialists making a fundamental mistake, or are they simply lacking information?

Comment: Platonists are not materialists, they assert the existence of an intangible and undetectable realm. A platonic world and a spiritual world seem to be closely related if not synonymous.

Comment: רמב"ם יסודי התורה א':ב'
ואם יעלה על הדעת שהוא אינו מצוי, אין דבר אחר יכול להימצאות.
If one would imagine that He does not exist, no other being could possibly exist.

Comment: @Nahum thanks for helping me sharpen the question. I will state here that my question precludes both of your previous points. The first is precluded by the fact that I do not think scientists and materialists nowadays who do not believe in ruchnius, think that mathematical forms are ruchni, and the second is precluded by the final paragraph

Comment: Math is descriptive. Platonic forms are the true underlying essence of stuff.

Comment: @Nahum, thanks for clarifying. Once again, I am precluding that philosophy from the question (unless you bring a Torah source that agrees that the Platonic world = Olam HaRuchni - note, that would defeat the question, because it would say that actually scientists do believe in an Olam Haruchni, which will be a weird answer but happy to consider it).

Comment: Materialist science, or scientism, does not believe in a platonic realm. Plato and Moses are similar to each other insofar as they posit that the phenomenological world is not the true and real world but rather that there exists a world beyond the physical one which is the primary and real one.

Comment: @Nahum For Aristotle, forms do not exist even though forms (as ideas) are real in inhering in things (as all things are made up of both matter and form) - just as the soul or mind does not exist, for Aristotle, even though real in being a function of the body. The Aristotelian conception of God is as the form of the universe.

Comment: The Rambam's statement quoted by @Nahum is the simplest statement of his answer to the question, the full explanation is in More Nevuchim 1:69

Comment: I remember an interview with Stephen Hawking included in a documentary about the structure of the universe from years ago. Hawking was describing how material existence on a quantum level constantly & continuously winks in & out of existence at different points in space, like a pointillist painting. That is why we perceive material existence as real. Then Hawking noted that “something” keeps pushing material existence to be maintained from outside of that domain. That is המחדש בכל יום תמיד מעשה בראשית.

Comment: @YaacovDeane thanks I still need to find that doc. Still, don't think it is relevant as that could just be an argument that the universe can't exist without Hashem, which is not being challenged here

Comment: The quantum physics and string theory is the “maths” that describe the עצמות. But like Hawking notes, עצמות is not מהות. That is really what you are asking. מהותו יתברך is transcendent, “outside of” existence. When Hawking described this, he was asked what “that” was. He smiled and said that was like asking what is “north” of the North Pole. A humorous and elegant comment about HaKadosh, baruch Hu.

Comment: @YaacovDeane very interesting but I am not asking about that. Let me go away from this and reframe the question completely to show why. A scientist today would say that there's no such thing as a soul beyond the body. The body itself produces consciousness and qualia. The aggregation of neural networking in the brain etc. Does Torah claim that this is impossible, a body can't produce consciousness, there **has** to be a spiritual entity called a soul? Hashem can make a body without a soul, yes, but _did_ He? Are the scientists stupid or are they being intelligent, they just happen to be wrong?

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/20008091

Comment: You are saying "some scientists", mostly those in the field of AI today, suggest that consciousness, which is loosely defined as "awareness of self", is nothing more than a complex & unique arrangement of data (meaning life experiences). They call this the "soul". This has partial validity in the sense that דבקות is achieved through learning Torah, including for example, the Torah of the Rebbe. That the עצמות of the Rebbe is his teachings, his Torah. But the Rebbe's soul is his מהות. Resurrection is the return of his soul (מהותו) into his reconstituted body (עצמותו).

Comment: You should take note that those "scientists", like Kubler-Ross and others who look at near-death experiences closely, say that consciousness, soul, continues even when the body, meaning heart and even primitive brain function ceases completely. This has been demonstrated with surgical resuscitation following brain surgery after draining the body, including the brain of all blood under low temperatures.

Comment: @Deuteronomy that link is spot on. Care to write a summary-answer?

Comment: @RabbiKaii oyy... hard to pass that over 'al regel ahath, and I don't think I've got the kishkes to make a larger treatment of it right now (its been some years since I've spent time thinking deeply about Leibowitz)... but I'm glad to have pointed you in a direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Ramchal](https://www.sefaria.org/Derekh_Hashem%2C_Part_One%2C_On_the_Spiritual_Realm.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes

> ראשי הנבראים הם כחות שמהם משתלשלים כלם: הנבראים הגשמיים ידועים הם אצלנו וחוקותיהם ומשפטיהם הטבעיים בכללם מפורסמים אך הרוחניים א״א לנו לצייר ענינם היטב כי הם חוץ מדמיוננו ונדבר בהם ובעניניהם רק כפי המסורת שבידנו. **והנה מן העיקרים הגדולים שבידנו בענין זה הוא שכנגד כל מה שנמצא בנמצאים השפלים נמצאים למעלה כחות נבדלים שמהם משתלשלים ויוצאים בסדר א׳‎ של השתלשלות שגזרה חכמתו ית׳‎. השפלים האלה הם ומיקריהם ונמצאים הכחות ההם שרשים לנמצאים השפלים האלה והנמצאים השפלים ענפים ותולדות לכחות ההם ונקשרים זה בזה כטבעות השלשלת**. עוד מסורת בידנו שעל כל עצם וכל מקרה שבנמצאים השפלים האלה הופקדו פקידים מן הסוג המלאכיי שזכרנו למעלה ומשאם לקיים העצם ההוא או המקרה ההוא בנמצאות השפלות כפי מה הוא ולחדש מה שראוי להתחדש בשפלים כפי הגזירה העליונה:
> **ואמנם עיקר מציאות העולם ומצבו האמיתי הוא בכחות ההם העליונים ותולדת מה שבהם הוא מה שבגשמים השפלים וזה בין במה שמתחלת הבריאה ובין במה שמתחדש בהתחלפות הזמנים והיינו כי כפי מה שנברא מן הכחות ההם וכפי הסידור שנסדרו והגבולים שהוגבלו כך היה מה שנשתלשל אח״כ לפי חק ההשתלשלות שרצה בו הבורא ית״ש וכפי מה שנתחדש ומתחדש בהם כך הוא מה שנתחדש ומתחדש בשפלים** אכן המציאות המצב והסדר וכל שאר ההבחנות בכחות הם כפי מה ששייך בהם לפי אמתת ענינים והמציאות והמצב והסדר וכל שאר המקרים בשפלים משתלשל ונעתק למה ששייך בהם לפי אמתת ענינם:
> ג׳‎ תנועות כלליות בבריאה: והנה לפי שרש זה תחלת כל ההויות למעלה בכחות העליונים וסופם למטה בשפלים וכן תחלת כל הענינים המתחדשים למעלה וסופם למטה. אמנם פרט א׳‎ יש שיוצא מן הכלל הזה הוא מה שנוגע לבחירתו של האדם כי כיון שרצה האדון ית״ש שיהיה היכולת לאדם לבחור במה שירצה מן הטוב ומן הרע הנה עשהו בלתי תלוי בה בזולתו ואדרבא נתן לו כח להיות מניע לעולם עצמו ולבריותיו כפי מה שיבחר בחפצו

> The physical creatures are known to us, and their axioms and their general natural properties are well-known. However it is impossible for us to have a proper picture of the spiritual [beings]; as they are beyond our imagination. So we will only speak about them and their makeup according to the tradition in our hands. **And see that among the great principles in our hands about this matter is that there are ethereal powers above, corresponding to everything that is found among the lower beings. It is from them that things unfold and proceed in a single line of cause and effect decreed by His wisdom, may He be blessed. The lower beings - they, their occurrences and their existence - are rooted in these powers; so these lower beings are extensions and effects of these powers. And one is connected to the other, like rings of a chain [of causation]**. Another tradition in our hands is that for every essence and every event among these lower being, supervisors from the angelic category we mentioned above are appointed. And their task is to preserve that essence or that event among the lower things, according to what it is, and to renew that which is appropriate to renew among the lowly beings, according to the Supreme decree.
> **In truth, the main existence of the world and its true state [occurs] through these higher powers. And the effects of that which [occurs with] them is [what occurs] to the lower physical beings. And this is whether it is beginning its creation, or it is developing as time passes. And this means that according to what is created from these powers, the order in which they are set and the limits that have been set up, that is what unfolds afterwards according to the axiom of unfolding that the Creator, may His name be blessed, willed. And according to that which develops and will develop among them, is what develops and will develop among the lower creatures.** Whereas the existence, condition, arrangement and all of the other distinctions among [the higher] powers are according to that which is appropriate for them in accordance with their true makeup; the existence, condition, arrangement and all of the other occurrences among the lower beings, unfold [from the spiritual beings] and are applied to that which is appropriate in them according to their true natures.
> Three general processes in creation: See that according to this root concept, the beginning of all events is above with the higher powers and their end is below with the lower creatures. And likewise, the beginning of all developments is above and their end is below. However there is one component that is an exception to this rule. And that is that which relates to man's free choice. For since the Master, may His name be blessed, wanted that man have the power to choose what he wants of good or evil, He made him independent of others. And just the opposite, [God] gave him the power to actually move the world and its creatures, according to that which he chooses with his will.

In other words, the universe is a series of linked worlds, each one deriving its existence from the one above it, all the way up to the first world created by Hashem.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an epidemic in our modern world. All science is empirically based upon sensory observation, however, our modern science is an extreme empiricism that is anti-metaphysical in nature. Our modern science says that nature is all there is. Yet, there are scientific assumptions, such as the law of nature, that nature is uniform, or the existence of the mind, which are non-empirical in nature. The mind is incorporeal. It cannot be measured or observed. We can observe a brain and a nervous system, we cannot observe the mind. Why do you assume that there is such a thing as mind. Yet we maintain that we have minds.

To answer your question. I can't think of any classical Jewish sources that could allow for a materialistic conception of the world other than the philosophy of Spinoza. I will attempt to explain the difference.

In a classical Jewish conception God creates nature and is completely outside of nature in transcending nature. God and nature are not identical. They are not the same thing.

For Spinoza, however, God is nature and nature is God. God and nature are identical as reflected in Spinoza's famous statement "God or nature". God is not outside of nature. We perceive only two attributes of the infinite number of attributes of God - thought (mental) and extension (physical-material). Everything in our world that we experience, which is only a small part of God (as God is infinite), is a mode of God.

If you want to call Spinoza a Jewish source then there is a Jewish conception that nature is all there is (allowing for a pantheistic conception of God) but I can't think of a single Torah source that would allow for such a view.

Comment: Thanks, the first paragraph is excellent and yes, thanks for explaining what Spinoza says on this.

Comment: @RabbiKaii I’m glad I was able to help. Your welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Chazal has said that the world stands on Torah, Avoda, Gemilut Chasidim. (2nd Mishna in pirkei avot)

In this question, we see that it is theoretically possible to have something stand on one leg, but it will be shaky.
[Why would Moshe's new nation have been considered a one legged chair?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/140815/why-would-moshes-new-nation-have-been-considered-a-one-legged-chair)

Thus this world could survive with just one of chazal's legs. Avoda probably won't work without Heaven to review the prayers but the other two might.

Edit: Torah alone wouldn't work. In your quest to destroy amalek you could declare war on everyone and nuke them. If your bombs use the principle of grama (indirect action), you're not chayiv for killing extra people and destroying the ecology.

Comment: I like the way you think